# setInterval теряется this

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема с потерей this.
Имеется у класса контроллер метод startGame (общается к классу модели), который вызывается при нажатии кнопки.

первый вариант все отрабатывает и показывает(разовый вызов при нажатии 1- вариант), как только заношу в setInterval(для переодического вызова 2-ой), this теряется. Не знаю как решить проблему(

```
    startGame(){

//1-ый вариант

this.matrix = this.model.createChangeMatrix(this.matrix, this.row, this.column, null, null);
return this.matrix;



//2-ой вариант

this.flagGame = setInterval(function() {
this.matrix = this.model.createChangeMatrix(this.matrix, this.row, this.column, null, null);
return this.matrix;
},1000);


}
```

Comment: вкратце итог из дубликата: либо сохраняй контекст *до* использования `var self = this;` и потом `self.matrix` и т.д, либо используй стрелочные функции, либо надо биндить `this` к функции

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло!